# Function definition from user input

Tags: scilab

I want to make a program where it will ask the user to enter a function, for example, `cos(x) + 2`. My problem is that, I do not know the syntax or the code on how to make the entered function become a real function where I can manipulate it, like get the derivative of it, plot it, something like that. Can anyone please teach me on how to do that? Thank you!

Comment: If you really would like some help, then I suggest that first please show some own effort to solve the problem, and if you get struck, then post a [mcve] about a particular problem or error. This is not an on demand tutorial site I think...

Comment: I would not come here if I already knew the answer. I wasn't able to find a solution for this for like 2 days due to lack of resources. All I know is that, x=input("Enter your function") is the syntax. But this only takes constant values, and x = input ("Enter your function", "s") also only takes a string. How can I do it where I can make the entered function become a real function and not some constant, or string, where I can manipulate it like plotting it or taking its derivative

Comment: All right, then please see my answer below. Does it help you to get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a "real" function, you can use 2 different syntaxes:

```
function [x]=myfct(a,b)
    x=a+b;
endfunction
```

or

```
deff("[x]=myfct(a,b)","x=a+b");
```

Note: if you have only one return varaible, you can omit the square brackets.

The latter form is more straightforward here, because you only need to ask 2 or 3 strings from the user:

1. function_statement: the answer should be `"x=a+b"`
2. input_varaible_list (separated by comas): the answer should be `"a,b"`
3. output_varaible_list (separated by comas): the answer should be `"x"`

Then put it together in a `deff`:

```
deff("["+output_varaible_list+"]=myfct("+input_varaible_list+")",function_statement);
```

If you fix the output variable name as `x`, then you don't have to ask for it, and the user have to enter only the right hand side of the function statement (after the `=`). So it becomes:

```
deff("[x]=myfct("+input_varaible_list+")","x="+function_statement);
```

For the derivative see the `derivative` and `numdiff` functions in the Scilab help.